# transfer data from Mysql to excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, report

I had created a website using **php**. In that website,I want to create a report like thing,which involves transferring details from one table to an excel sheet which is downloadable.Is there any way to do this work? Please help me to find the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: The [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/downloads/get/212184) utility.

Comment: So what efforts have you already made?

Comment: The tag below the question implies MySQL, the question title implies MS-SQlServer. Please be specific to the question.

Comment: is there any otherway without using anyplugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all rows from the database and use fputcsv function to put it as csv

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

$csvHandler = fopen("php://output", 'w');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($res))
{
    fputcsv($csvHandler, $row);
}
```

Comment: when i executed this it generated excel sheet with html file contents.so can you tell me what could have gone wrong?

Comment: sorry,I made some mistake.now its working fine.Thank you.But could i able to set column name also through php?

Comment: but this displays a column two times.

Comment: For setting column name, create an array of column names and then use fputcsv($csvHandler, $colNameArray) just before the while loop

Comment: you mean instead of $row i should pass array of vol names?

Comment: Yes, but not insider while loop, just before the while loop. For example, if you want to list Id, Name, Email, Username as column name on the top then create an array $colNameArray = array ("Id", "Name", "Email", "Username");

Comment: If you need name of all columns returned by query, then you can use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array. This will return array of (columnname, columnvalue) pair and then you can use array_keys to print column names and array_values to print column values

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for generating data

and a simple function for file download:

```
function show_download($data, $name, $type = "unknown/unknown") {
header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

print $data;

exit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script that exports a CSV file like this :

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=clients_" . date("Ymd") . ".csv");

//Open PHP output stream
$fd = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$tab = array();

//get your results from your database
foreach ($results as $res)
   $tab[] = array($res->Client_Name, $res->Client_Email);

foreach ($tab as $val)
    fputcsv($fd, $val);

fclose($fd);
```

Comment: I am getting error invalid argument supplied for foreach().my select query looks like this     
**$query1 = "select * from login ";                 $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error());**